# Python tk scrollbar on listbox not working in windows 10

Tags: python, tkinter, windows-10, listbox, scrollbar

I have python3 tk code that seems to work okay in linux (ubuntu) but bizarely does not work in windows 10. The scrollbar on the listbox doesn't scroll in windows ...

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
root.title("My MHT")
root.geometry("500x500")

# create all of the main containers
toppest_frame = tk.Frame(root, bg='thistle3', width=500, height=25, pady=3)
top_frame = tk.Frame(root, bg='cyan', width=500, height=250, pady=3)
bottom_frame = tk.Frame(root, bg='lavender', width=500, height=250, pady=3)

# layout all of the main containers
root.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
root.grid_rowconfigure(1, weight=1)
root.grid_rowconfigure(2, weight=1)
root.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

toppest_frame.grid(row=0, sticky="nesw")
top_frame.grid(row=1, sticky="nesw")
bottom_frame.grid(row=2, sticky="nesw")

#create scrollbar
sb1 = tk.Scrollbar(top_frame,orient="vertical")
sb1.grid(row=0,column=5)

sb2 = tk.Scrollbar(top_frame,orient="horizontal")
sb2.grid(row=1,columnspan=5)

# create the widgets for the top frame
listBox = tk.Listbox(top_frame, relief="sunken",bd=2,selectmode="single")

# layout the widgets in the top frame
top_frame.grid_rowconfigure(0,weight=1)
top_frame.grid_columnconfigure(0,weight=1)
listBox.grid(row=0,sticky="nesw",columnspan=5)

#populate listbox
listBox.delete(0, "end")
for values in range(100):
    listBox.insert("end", values)

#attach scrollbar to listbox
listBox.configure(xscrollcommand=sb1.set)
sb1.configure(command=listBox.yview)

listBox.configure(yscrollcommand=sb2.set)
sb2.configure(command=listBox.xview)

root.mainloop()
```

Am I doing something wrong?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not know how you got this to work in Linux with `tkinter`, but anyway you are setting the scrollbar for the wrong axis.

```
listBox.configure(yscrollcommand=sb1.set) # Was xscrollcommand
sb1.configure(command=listBox.yview)

listBox.configure(xscrollcommand=sb2.set) # Was yscrollcommand
sb2.configure(command=listBox.xview)
```

Then you also need the scrollbar to expand along its field, with `grid` you use `sticky`, if you were using `pack` then an appropriate combination of `fill` and `side`, sometimes `expand` too:

```
sb1 = tk.Scrollbar(top_frame,orient="vertical")
sb1.grid(row=0,column=5,sticky='ns') # Expand north to south

sb2 = tk.Scrollbar(top_frame,orient="horizontal")
sb2.grid(row=1,columnspan=5,sticky='ew') # Expand east to west
```

I also hope you have a good reason to use `columnspan=5` and did not get it confused with `column`. Ideally in this situation, it should be column 1 and 0 for `sb1` and `sb2` respectively.